# How to retrieve hyperlink data type column value in sharepoint list using client object model of javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have many fields in my share point custom list one of them is of hyperlink data type.Which i have named as URL....While using client object model i am not able to fetch the data whose data type hyperlink.
i am using,

```
get_title('URL')
```

function.but it returns object type.but i need the exact url value how to get it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add **.get_url()** after the field name

For example:

myListItem.get_fieldValues()["WebPage"].get_url()